# component connect one labtop to two monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a HP monitor and a Samsung monitor, and would like to let my labtop connect to these two monitors, one of which as monitor 1, and the other on as monitor 2. Which kind of component I have to purchase? Both labtop and two monitors have HDMI.  Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking for hardware shopping recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, everything uses HDMI, so you want HDMI cables… a more detailed question might get a more detailed answer.